# How to change the sub-tags of Equations and the cross-references accordingly?

Tags: cleveref, subequations

I am trying to modify the following labels for the letters to be capital letters. I also need the cross-references (using cleverref) to match the newly defined style. There are several related questions, but I couldn't mix up all the knowledge out there to come up with what I need. There goes a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb} % MATH PACKAGES
\usepackage{cleveref} % FOR FANCY REFERENCES

\begin{document}
Look what a fancy optimisation problem in \cref{p} subject to \cref{c1,c2}, folks!
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{alignat}{2}\label{p}
        & \max_{L,\mathbf{x}} & & v(L) - \sum_{i \in L} \delta \cdot x_i\\\label{c1} 
        & \text{subject to} &\quad & \mathbf{x} \in \mathfrak{C}(\mathfrak{L},v)\\\label{c2}
        & & & x_i \geqslant \delta \cdot x_i^{*} \forall \text{ Players }i\in N \text{ such that } \omega_i < \omega_j
    \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

There goes the current output:

[image]

**What I need are letters A, B and C in capital form everywhere**.

Thank you all in advance for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does what you want. The `{subequations}` environment hardcodes the behavior that says that subequations should be written as lowercase letters `\alph{equation}`. This uses `\patchcmd` from the `etoolbox` package to replace `\alph{equation}` with a handle `\thechildequation` which you can define as you like.

This patching must be done before loading the `cleverref` package because `cleverref` defines it's own wrapper around the original `{subequations}` environment so it can add its own handling (it moves the original `\subequations` into `\cref@old@subequations`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb} % MATH PACKAGES
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\subequations{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}{\theparentequation\thechildequation}{}{\error} % Must come before loading cleverref
\usepackage{cleveref} % FOR FANCY REFERENCES
\newcommand*{\thechildequation}{\Alph{equation}}
\begin{document}
Look what a fancy optimisation problem in \cref{p} subject to \cref{c1,c2}, folks!
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{alignat}{2}\label{p}
        & \max_{L,\mathbf{x}} & & v(L) - \sum_{i \in L} \delta \cdot x_i\\\label{c1}
        & \text{subject to} &\quad & \mathbf{x} \in \mathfrak{C}(\mathfrak{L},v)\\\label{c2}
        & & & x_i \geqslant \delta \cdot x_i^{*} \forall \text{ Players }i\in N \text{ such that } \omega_i < \omega_j
    \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Three different great answers appeared within seconds. I accept yours just because you were the first one! Thank you.

Comment: +1, but you should say `\newcommand{\thechildequation}{\Alph{equation}}` (or, even better according to my taste, `\newcommand*{\thechildequation}{\Alph{equation}}`.

Comment: Okay, I edited it just for you @GuM.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution: defining a `Subequations` environment (`\renewwenvironment{subequations}` would also work). I corrected some spacing problems, and propose another alignment, which looks nicer, in my opinion:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb} % MATH PACKAGES
\usepackage{cleveref} % FOR FANCY REFERENCES

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\Alph{equation}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Look what a fancy optimisation problem in \cref{p} subject to \cref{c1,c2}, folks!
    \begin{Subequations}
    \begin{alignat}{2}\label{p}
        & \max_{L,\mathbf{x}} & & v(L) - \sum_{i \in L} \delta \cdot x_i\\\label{c1}
        & \text{subject to} &\quad & \mathbf{x} \in \mathfrak{C}(\mathfrak{L},v)\\\label{c2}
        & & & x_i \geqslant \delta \cdot x_i^{*}\quad \forall \text{ Players }i\in N \text{ such that } \omega_i < \omega_j
    \end{alignat}
    \end{Subequations}

    \begin{Subequations}
    \begin{alignat}{2}\label{q}
         \max_{L,\mathbf{x}} & & & v(L) - \sum_{i \in L} \delta \cdot x_i\\\label{d1}
       \text{subject to} & &\quad & \mathbf{x} \in \mathfrak{C}(\mathfrak{L},v)\\\label{d2}
        & & & x_i \geqslant \delta \cdot x_i^{*} \quad \forall \text{ Players }i\in N \text{ such that } \omega_i < \omega_j
    \end{alignat}
    \end{Subequations}

    \begin{Subequations}
    \begin{alignat}{2} %\label{r}
          & \max_{L,\mathbf{x}} \quad \mathrlap{v(L) - \sum_{i \in L} \delta \cdot x_i} \\[0.5ex] \label{e1}
      & \text{subject to} & \quad \smash{\rule[-4.5ex]{0.5pt}{6.5ex}\;}& \mathbf{x} \in \mathfrak{C}(\mathfrak{L},v) \\\label{e2}
      & & & x_i \geqslant \delta \cdot x_i^{*} \quad \forall \text{ Players }i\in N \text{ such that } \omega_i < \omega_j
    \end{alignat}
    \end{Subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate the alternative alignment. I accepted another equally useful answer that appeared first. Thank you!

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach will not be compatible with cleverref without modification.

Comment: @HoodChatham: ???  It seems to work, just look at the result.

Comment: @Héctor: I've added a third possibility.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure. If you `\show\subequations` after loading cleverref, you'll see that cleverref has redefined it to be a wrapper. This is presumably in order to get some cleverref feature to work correctly -- I'm not sure what. There's a description on line 6527 of cleverref.dtx here: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.dtx

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine the `subequations` environment. Just put this in your preamble after loading `amsmath` and before `cleverref`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%           VVVV - Changed to "Alph"
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\Alph{equation}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
```

The redefinition is necessary because the `\theequation` is defined each time the environment is called, so it is not possible (as far as I know) to define just the label.

Comment: Make sure that you do this before loading cleverref though!

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks! But why?

Comment: cleverref changes the definition of `\subequations` to add some wrapper code and then call the original version of `\subequations` which it saves in `\cref@old@subequations`. If you do this after loading cleverref, it deletes cleverref's wrapper code.